# Utilities/Platform missing for react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I trying to run expo-cli in browser mode.

But there is the error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '../../Utilities/Platform' in
>   '.../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers'.

I tried also to look manually for this module but no luck.

What can I do to make expo client works in web browsers?

Comment: please provide a link to a repository that reproduces this issue. if you initialize a project with `expo init` and then run `expo start` in that directory and press `w` to open web, it works without the error you referred to.

see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a module resolver plugin to resolve dependencies to the React Native Web exports might help you. React-native-viewpager has an issue with resolving relative paths. See this comment and this entire thread: https://github.com/expo/web-examples/issues/73#issuecomment-621078860 and sample repo here: https://github.com/ricardoribas/expo-react-native-web

Comment: The second link is no longer active. Would you be able to explain how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can also config your webpack. You can use 'expo customize:web'. This will install `@expo/webpack-config` as development dependency an create a `webpack.config.js`.

You can define aliases on this configuration like this:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config')

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv)
  config.resolve.alias['../Utilities/Platform'] =
    'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform'
  return config
}
```

This should resolve your issue

Comment: I'm getting " Cannot find module '@expo/webpack-config'
Require stack:".  And underneath, is a list with items like: "AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Webpack.js"

Comment: Try install manually `npm i --save-dev @expo/webpack-config` or `yarn -D @expo/webpack-config` . It seems like a dependency problem. Did `expo customize:web` installed ok?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this but isn't looking to use expo in the web, the solution is to remove this line from app.json

```
"web": {
  "bundler": "metro"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, If you experience this error and you have done  re-install on your packages and the error still remain, Now check all your import, there must be something your are suppose to import form react-native that you are importing from somewhere else if you can find this this error will be fixed what you can do  is to identify the actual wrong import

For me I do:

```
import Pressable from "reactnative/Libraries/Components/Pressable/Pressable
```

Instead of:

```
import {Pressable } from "react-native";
```